Why is my band pass filter giving a gain of 0.5 in the -3 dB gain region?
I designed a band pass circuit but it gives me a gain of 0.5 in the band region. Shouldn't it be 0.707?



So how did you calculate the values of the design, i.e. under which assumptions?

@Justme Hi my center frequancy is nearly 55khz  band with is 5,5 hz

Have you plotted the frequency response? How'd you verify the centre frequency and the bandwidth?

@RohatKılıç it was given in my assignment they said take your last two number of your student id as a center freq

@serkan OK so we have a bandbpass with a center freq of 55 kHz, from where the bandwidth comes? Also why do you assume it should be 0.707 instead of 0 5, given that center frequency and bandwidth, implemented with a high pass and low pass?

@Justme they said take bandwith as  %10 of 55 so bandwith 5510/100=5.5  hertz 2pi*5,5=B right?

@serkan We don't know what your task is or how to interpret what it means. You need to be sure if you want 10% of 55 Hz or 10% or 55 kHz. Either can be done and since it is a school assignment it does not need to make sense in real life.

@Justme it's  %10 of 55 not kilo and according to the bandpass filter graphics in low cutoff  freq and in  high cutoff freq it says -3db gain that makes 0.707

The good thing is that you have tried to make the two sections of filter not interact with each other by using impedances that are 100 times bigger for the second stage compared to the first stage.

Your filter is formed by cascading a high-pass filter with a low-pass filter
Both have the same cut-off frequencies (\$RC_{LP} = RC_{HP}\$) therefore,
Both introduce an attenuation of 0.7071 at the cut-off frequency

The net result is an attenuation at the cut-off frequency of 0.7071 x 0.7071 = 0.5. You can see that if you used a simulator set to perform an AC analysis: -

At the mid-point in the circuit (the output of the HP section), you can see that the loss at ~55 kHz is about 3 dB and, the loss at the output is double this hence, both sections attenuate by roughly 3 dB at the mid-frequency of the band-pass filter.

Thanks for that ı thought the same but  I am sure right now.

@serkan if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

To highlight the 6-dB attenuation at the center frequency, you can use the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs to derive a low-entropy transfer function. If you do the maths ok, then you see a center at 55 kHz and an attenuation of 0.5 or 6 dB:

You can either arrange the transfer function as a second-order polynomial in which you have a quality factor and a resonant frequency or consider a low-\$Q\$ approximation and cascade a pole with an inverted pole. As the Mathcad plots show, the difference between the three expression is minimum.

It might be easiest to see from this run:

The constraints I used were to set up \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$ to possess the high-pass frequency indicated by the fixed HP parameter shown, \$55\:\text{kHz}\$, and to use your value for \$C_1\$ and to let \$R_1\$ fall out from there.
I then set the quadrature impedance of \$C_2\$ and \$R_2\$ to be \$100\times\$ greater and set their values such that their crossover frequency was determined by the LP parameter, which was varied between \$55\:\text{kHz}\$ and \$5.5\:\text{MHz}\$.
Above, I set the cursors to where the \$\approx -3.0103\:\text{dB}\$ point was located. When the bandpass is wide enough, as it is for the case of the passband being \$55\:\text{kHz}\$ to \$5.5\:\text{MHz}\$, you get the \$\approx -3.0103\:\text{dB}\$ points at about where you expect. There is a tiny offset. But this is only because one of the filters (the LP one) does load down the other and also because there is still a tiny remaining effect of one filter on the other at their corners. Even the expected phase is near \$45^\circ\$ at both crossovers.
The point here is that when the lowpass and highpass filters are far away from each other and don't otherwise load down each others' responses, then you get expected results.
However, as you pinch them together -- and especially if you set their corners on top of each other -- then you expect far more impact of one upon the other:

The red line shows it where both corners are on top of each other. Then the \$\approx -3.0103\:\text{dB}\$ point of the highpass and lowpass are on top of each other and you get nearly double the attenuation of \$\approx -6.0206\:\text{dB}\$. And the phase is near zero at that point.

You are using such values for resistors and capacitors that end up having a peak gain of approximately -6dB at 54.9 kHz. You can verify this in many ways like doìng the math on paper, using a simulator, or any filter calculator to where you can enter your component values.
So the assumption of having 0.707 at 55 kHz is incorrect.
What you might be missing is that you have two filters and each one of them has a -3dB point at 55 kHz so the two filters have a total of -6dB at 55 kHz.
